# npm install -g cordova, npm install -g ionic on Windows10

Tags: node.js, cordova, ionic-framework

I was trying to do push notifications using angular and ionic, i was getting few issues while i was running Command prompt.

So i had to uninstall node.js and i tried to re-install the node.js , it installed successfully as i verified by node -v then it showed me v4.4.2

Then i tried to install cordova, ionic by using following commands:

```
npm install -g cordova 
npm install -g ionic
```

it throwed following errors:

```
module.js:327
    throw err;
    ^

Error: Cannot find module 'C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\bin\node_modules\npm\bin\npm-cli.js'
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:325:15)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:276:25)
    at Function.Module.runMain (module.js:441:10)
    at startup (node.js:139:18)
    at node.js:968:3
 module.js:327
    throw err;
    ^

Error: Cannot find module 'C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\bin\node_modules\npm\bin\npm-cli.js'
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:325:15)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:276:25)
    at Function.Module.runMain (module.js:441:10)
    at startup (node.js:139:18)
    at node.js:968:3
```

Can someone help me how to resolve this issue, as i tried multiple times and restarted my pc.[cordova issue](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0wYnE.png)

Please check the attached image for the reference and let me know what changes / how to resolve this issue

Comment: It seems that `npm` was installed incorrectly. Could you run `where npm` or `npm -version`?

Comment: I did it worked well, i saw the solution for this on stack overflow.

Comment: SET PATH=C:\Program Files\Nodejs;%PATH% , It worked, Thank you once again